# Cannot remove tag from title - error message tells me nothing

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, title

I tried to remove the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag from the title of the question [C# Why does Web browser Drop Down Does Not Update The Price?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18710022/109702), but when I went to save the edit I was presented with an error that told me nothing.

[image]

This is a type of edit that I've performed probably a thousand times or more, so I'm curious as to why it would fail this time. It still fails if I refresh the page and try again. It doesn't appear to be a duplicate title as totally changing the title didn't work either.

I'm a developer and I don't like it when an error message effectively says: *"Bzzzzt!! Error! Try again!"*. Can the error functionality be changed to actually tell us what the problem is so that we can tell immediately whether we are beating a dead horse or not?

Comment: Not sure why but I didn't get any error after just removing `C#` from the title.

Comment: It appears to be this specific question - I tried adding the tag back in and got the same message. I've edited a couple of other arbitrary question titles successfully (so it's not a localised problem).

Comment: Perhaps a connection interrupt? Any error reported in console?